# Intersection of countable many open sets on a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an irreducible variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. Suppose $U_i$, $i\in \mathbb{N}$ are nonempty open (Zariski open) sets of $X$. If $k$ is uncountable, why the intersection $$\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} U_i$$ is nonempty?

Comment: The dual question-why the union of countably many closed subsets, i.e. subvarieties or subschemes, of $X$ can't be $X$, was discussed at MathOverflow not too long ago. It's not completely easy, and I'm unfortunately not the right person to expound either of the given proofs in more detail. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73743/countable-union-of-closed-subschemes-over-uncountable-field

If $k=\Bbb{C}$, then the Baire category theorem gives an easier proof.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this to me!